# Curl based magento API creation

Tags: php, api, soap, magento2, rest-api

I am planning to create a URL Based api which enable me to fetch resources using curl. 
For example, If a client can request the resource by using the following url structure.

`curl -some-variable http://mydomainname/magentoroot/api.php?func=addtwonum&parama=34&paramb=11`

It should produce response within xml or json. Assume public key and private key encryption and decryption are done.

Is it a feasible method?? Or shall I go to REST or SOAP. I am much inclined to this method.

Comment: You can use `$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($your_result));` in your controller to produce response json data.

Answer (score 2):

I would use REST. Magento 2 comes with REST APIs standard, and its easy to create a webapi.xml file to bind REST URLS to your own APIs you introduce as well. See http://devdocs.magento.com then go to "web services developer" in the menu bar. There are examples using CURL there as well.

Comment: I just created a blog post giving an example of building a simple REST service at https://alankent.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/.